# Using custom SpEL method in spring XD stream definition

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-xd

My idea is to create custom SpEL method and register that in a spring XD module.

I have following in my spring XD module XML

```
<int:spel-function class="com.digitalmessagingsystem.batch.batchdsvalidator.util.Sample" 
            method="sampleMethod(java.lang.String sampleStr)" id="sampleSpEL"/>
```

I want to use this custom SpEL function in spring XD stream definition like

```
stream create inputStream --definition "file --dir=C:/springXD/ds_data --outputType=text/plain | splitter --expression=#{T(com.digitalmessagingsystem.batch.batchdsvalidator.util.Sample).sampleMethod(payload)} | output:log "  --deploy
```

Is this valid?

I am getting error in singlenode console like Type `com.digitalmessagingsystem.batch.batchdsvalidator.util.Sample`

can't be found.

Any suggestion please ?